# Button to show the version of the question as of when answer was posted / last edited?

Tags: feature-request, edits, questions, answers, revisions-list

Sometimes when reading an answer it doesn't seem to correspond entirely to the question asked, and if I want to find out why the procedure then becomes:

1. Scroll up to the question again
2. Check if it has been edited
3. Scroll back down to the answer again, because you forgot to check the time and date it was posted/last edited
4. Try to remember the answer's time and date
5. Scroll up to the question
6. Check if the question's edit date was before the answer's date
7. If not, browse the edit history to manually find the latest version before the answer date
8. Try to remember the answer well enough to judge whether it makes more sense in this new (old) context

I think it would be helpful if there were a badge or notification next to an answer informing me that the question has been edited since the answer was posted or last edited, accompanied by a button to show me the version of the question that was actually answered.

Apart from the obvious benefit of not having to go through all these steps it might also help avoid misunderstandings in the comments as well as downvotes as a result of not answering the most recent version of the question.

This same problem regularly occurs with "outdated" comments as well.

Comment: If a question edit invalidates existing useful answers, seriously consider rolling back that edit.

Comment: @PM2Ring The alert here would alert users to perform said rollback.

Comment: @PM2Ring Unfortunately, the policy that question edits which invalidate one or more answers should be rolled-back is not universal across all SE sites. Some sites have explicitly decided that such edits to the question should result in the answers being updated.

Comment: @Makyen Interesting... I doubt I'd enjoy participating on such sites. OTOH, I've certainly updated my own answers to well-formed questions where the OP accidentally omitted some crucial info, and only realised it after answers started rolling in. That can be tolerable if it only requires minor adjustments to the answers. Otherwise, not only does it put answerers at the whim of the OP making unexpected changes, it can also mess up the correct ranking of the answers if voters aren't aware that posts they voted on have been radically altered.

Answer (score 3):

> I think it would be helpful if there were a badge or notification next to an answer informing me that the question has been edited since the answer was posted or last edited, accompanied by a button to show me the version of the question that was actually answered.

I don't think the badge or notification could actually become a *useful sign*, not unless Stack Exchange starts differentiating edits based on the changes they made (which I don't see happening anytime soon). Posts are edited on these sites all the time. And nine times out of 10, it's just someone fixing some spelling or grammatical error, or adding/removing a tag, adding a question mark to a title, or any other edits that don't significantly change the meaning of a post.

A badge or notification beside each answer, for each time an edit to the question is made, will soon become nothing more than noise: As long as it doesn't say anything about the kind of edit made, it also doesn't help determine whether it's worth my time to check the revision history of the question or not. Also, what if someone was editing the question, then edited the answer for spelling/grammar too? No notification, so you're still on your own.

As for the button to jump to the revision that was answered, it falls prone to the same shortcomings as having a notification:

- You can have it always jump to the original version of the question (revision 1). In case both the question and the answer have been heavily edited over time though, this would be pretty useless, you'd still end up searching for the 'right' revision.
- You could have it jump to the version of the question at the time the answer was posted. This would make no sense if the answer was significantly edited after that.
- You could have it jump to the version of the question that was there when an edit to the answer was made. Now you have an answer edited for grammar/spelling that doesn't link to the original question it answered anymore.

As for comments: Well, editing something for spelling/grammatical errors again doesn't automatically mean the comment becomes outdated. I'm afraid comment flagging will remain something that requires a human to differentiate between stuff that's indeed fixed by an edit, and things that aren't. There are already accounts out there that raise comment flags based on keywords, without actually evaluating the comment. I don't think a notification that a comment was posted before an edit is going to make for much better flags.

I'm afraid you'll be stuck with manual work for this, as right now I don't see the system becoming smart enough to differentiate, and *know* which version of the question belongs with which version of an answer. In general, this is why the [help center](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) advises to only answer well-asked questions, and why [chameleon questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43478/369802) are frowned upon.

---

I think instead, you can streamline your 'manual' process a bit by using several browser tabs: if you forget to check the time/date an answer was posted edited, just already keep the edit date of the question in mind, and open the revision history in a new browser tab. Then scroll down to the answer again, take its time/date, and on your second tab, scroll to the corresponding entry in the revision history.

Or, you could just leave a comment anyways without checking the entire revision history, that leaves open the possibility of the question having changed: "Hey X! I see the *current* question is asking about apples, your answer seems mostly written for pears. Could you perhaps consider adding more information about apples?"

Comment: Using the timeline to locate possibly relevant edits can be a little faster than directly examining the entire revision history.